# How to Open Hebrew Keyboard Input on Mobile HTML Site

Tags: html, keyboard, hebrew

When a user fills in details on my site I would like to open a Hebrew keyboard for text input in mobile devices. 
I'm not looking for validators or regexes, but for Hebrew keyboard.
Is it possible in Html?

Answer (score 0):

This cannot be done with HTML5 inputs.